# Creating a unique short ID from string value

Tags: python, hashlib

I have some data that has unique IDs stored as a string in the form:

```
ddd.dddddaddd.dddddz
```

Where `d` is some digit and `a`/`z` is some alphabet character. The digits may be 0-9 and the characters are either `E` or `W` for the `a` and `N` or `S` for the `z`.

I'd like to turn this into a unique integer and what I've tried using the `hashlib` module returns:

```
>>> int(hashlib.sha256(str.encode(s)).hexdigest(), 16)
Output: a very long integer (on another system cannot copy it)
```

Is there a way to generate a unique integer ID from a string so that it does not exceed 12 digits? I know that I will never need a unique integer ID beyond 12 digits.

Comment: What digits and what alphabet characters are allowed?

Comment: @superbrain digits: 0-9, alphabet: E, S, W, N. Updated the OP.

Comment: How are 16 digits and 2 letters supposed to fit into 12 digits?

Comment: @superbrain I was not aware they had to fit into the desired length, thought the string could go through some "magical funnel" and pump out a unique hash. If the hash must be longer than the strings, 20 digits is fine as well.

Comment: Please post running code. There is no `sha25` and you have the parenthesis wrong. The example suggests that "Output: a very long integer (on another system cannot copy it)" is literally the output of `int()`.

Comment: @tdelaney As said, cant copy over; no Python on the system that has commercial net access. Updated code snippet. The result from the `int()` call is a number that is 77 digits long: `len(str(int(hashlib.sha256(str.encode(s)).hexdigest(), 16)))`.

Comment: So clearly these are lat/long coordinates? Do you need the full precision?

Comment: Since it's coordinates, a reduction to 12 integers would reduce the information of the ID. If the points are not too close together, degrees and minutes might suffice (5 digits) and you would just need one integer (1,2,3,4) to indicate the quadrant (NE,SE,SW,NW). So, 11 integers would be possible and you could reconstruct the initial ID. If two IDs are identical, you can use the 12th integer as a counter. So, 10 points might lie less than 1 minute apart.

Comment: Even at 64 characters, `sha256` isn't unique, but you'd have to be pretty unlucky to hit duplicates. `md5` does 32 digits, but you don't have to be nearly as unlucky to hit one. Down to 12 digits isn't quite Vegas odds, but not very good for uniqueness.

Comment: Perhaps the sphere could be divided into 2**12 regions and the coordinates could be normalized to whatever region its in. I have no idea how big any one of those regions would be, but that may be the best chance of uniqueness you've got. Simply rounding down would be an easy way of doing that.

Comment: @superbrain Correct, we currently use the center points of a grid as the unique ID  for each element in the tessellation. We really only need about 3 digits of precision.

Comment: @MartinWettstein Two ID's would never be identical. They currently represent the centers of each tile in a grid spanning from -180/180/-90/90. There is no longitudinal wrap in the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just something simple:

```
>>> s = '123.45678W123.45678S'
>>> int(s.translate(str.maketrans('EWNS', '1234', '.')))
123456782123456784
```

Not the impossible 12 digits you're still asking for in the question, but under the 20 digits you allowed in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

As you are dealing with coordinates, I would try my best to keep the information in the final 12-digit ID.

- If your points are global, it might be necessary to keep the degrees but they may be widespread, so you can sacrifice some information when it comes to precision.
- If your points are local (all within a range of less than 10 degrees) you might skip the first two digits of the degrees and focus on the decimals.
- As it may be possible that two points are close to each other, it may be prudent to reserve one digit as a serial number.

Proposal for widespread points:

```
s = "123.45678N123.45678E"
ident = "".join([s[0:6],s[10:16]]).replace(".","")
q = 0
if s[9]=="N":
    q+=1
if s[-1]=="E":
    q+=2
ident+=str(q)+'0'
```

The example would translate to `123451234530`.

After computing the initial `ident` numbers for each ID, you should loop through them and increment the last digit if an `ident` is already taken.

This way you could easily reconstruct the location from the ID by just separating the first 10 digits to two degrees of the format ddd.dd and use the [-2] digit as an indicator of the quadrant (0:SW, 1:SE, 2:NW, 3:NE).